# How to avoid $escape parameter in fgetcsv/fputcsv functions

Tags: php, escaping, double-quotes, fgetcsv

I am not sure for what can be the parameter good.

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]]] )
```

Default value is backslash. CSV specification does not need any escape character. The enclosure character in value is doubled and both delimiters or newlines make no problems when the value is enclosed. I have such row in the CSV file:

```
"value1 can contain qoutes like this (""), comma (,) and
new line","value2\"" contains desired backslash, quote and later comma.","value3 is simple"
```

The result is unwanted. Forcing escape character in the last parameter breaks reading this row and produces 4 values instead of 3. The backslash in value2 will eat the first quote and the second quote is supposed as enclosing character. Then the later comming coma works as unwanted item separator.

How can I avoid using any escape characters? Passing empty string causes warning "Single character must be passed". Passing some improbable character will help (proved) but it is not reliable when I am working with more multilanguage 8-bit encoding (windows-1250, windows-1252, windows-1256 etc.)

Comment: there is no "csv specification". there's just a general "it kinda sorta mostly usually looks like this" agreement, but everyone app can/will do it differently. some will escape quotes as `\"`, and some will escape as `""`. you can make a csv that will work everywhere. you can only make a csv that will work with some particular app. And yes, you do need an escape if the data you're embedding contains the character used to delimit that field. is `Smith, Fred` one single field (aka full name), or is it two fields: firstname,lastname?

Comment: @MarcB That's handled by wrapping them with `$enclosure`: `"Smith, Fred"`.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but have you tried passing `null`?

Comment: @Barmar: and what if the field contains the enclosure char itself? That's why you need escapes. `"Fred"Smith"`

Comment: @MarcB He shows that in the question: you double it `"Fred""Smith"`.

Comment: but `""` is an escape sequence, specific for Excel-type csvs. So basically this makes no sense whatsoever "can't use escapes at all, but have to use escapes"

Comment: I have enhanced the example. The comma inside the second item is important. It causes item break. @Marc B: Maybe there is no CSV standard, but if I must process CSV from third party that uses no escape character, then I must specify one, because its passing is mandatory.

Comment: @Barmar: null parameter produces the same warning and the function returns null.

Comment: It looks like [this library](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php/blob/master/parsecsv.lib.php) uses doubled doublequotes instead of backslash escapes.